# Check for draw_texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I wanna check if the draw_texture function is avaiable on the actual device, so:

**How can I check if this extension is supported?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if this extension is supported?

Scan the string returned by [`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGetString.xml) for [`GL_OES_draw_texture`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what about the others? Do you know about them?

Comment: Nope.  The extension spec should give you some insight though.